# jquery append problem

Tags: jquery, input

I have an input (at chat) and emoticons.
I need to set when some body click on emoticon, to add its code to the input(without deleting the current text)
For example I have written:
"Hello " I press the smile image and the input must become 
"Hello :):" !!! NOT SUBMITED still at the input field!

```
$("img.emots").click(function() { var emots=$(this).attr("title"); 
    $("#message_text").append(emots); });
```

I use this but its not working (its putting the emoticon between input tags `<input>HERE</input>`

What I need to do ??? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("img.emots").click(function() { 
    var emots= $(this).attr("title"); 
    var $txt = $("#message_text");
    $txt.val($txt.val() + " " + emots); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.append` is for appending *child nodes* to a node. An `input` element does not have any children. You have to change its *value*, using [`.val()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#message_text").val(function(i, value){
    return value + emots;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>HERE</input>` is not valid markup. Try `<textarea>HERE</textarea>` and then

```
$("img.emots").click(function() { 
    var emots=$(this).attr("title"); 
    $("textarea").val($("textarea").val()+emots); 
});
```